# Доступ к дисплею удаленного сервера Xvfb

Tags: администрирование

Возможно ли на локальной машине с OS X увидеть что происходит на дисплее удаленного сервера с Xvfb?

Comment: Можно видеть конкретные приложения. Скажем запустить приложение на удаленном сервере (с Xvfb) и видеть все его окна на "OS X", и наоборот. Или нужно именно целиком дисплей Xvfb?

Comment: @user1034749 Необходимо увидеть конкретное приложение. На линукс сервере работает селениум с хромом, и хочется увидеть на локальном OS X что там реально происходит, не через скриншоты.

Comment: Если с перезапуском, то можно зайти удаленно по ssh с опцией -X/-Y и запустить приложение из командной строки, тогда приложение будет запущено на удаленном сервере, а показывать окно на OS X.